# How to populate Frontend Article Editor with existing Article content, Joomla 4?

Tags: joomla-4.x, front-end, editing

We are building a new site founded on Joomla 4, and would like to only use core extension like the Article features built into Joomla 4, but we've run into a wall trying to implement editing an article from the Frontend of the site. We've found an effective way to get an article that we want to edit to display within the Article Editor on the Frontend except it fails to come up with the content included in the original (it comes up blank). What do we need to do to get the content of the selected, existing article to be included for editing on the Frontend of the site? I've included screen captures showing how we get the Event Editor to display on the Frontend and the resulting, blank, unpopulated editor.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE Fred, please take our [tour].